# GAM R variance explained by variable

Tags: r, variance, gam, mgcv

My current problem is to calculate the variance explained by the different variables of a general additive model (GAM) with R.

I followed the explanation given by Wood here :
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-October/142743.html

But I would like to do it with three variables. 
I tried this :

```
library(mgcv)

set.seed(0)
n<-400
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1) 
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1) 

f1 <- function(x) exp(2 * x) - 3.75887
f2 <- function(x) 0.2*x^11*(10*(1-x))^6+10*(10*x)^3*(1-x)^10
f3 <- function(x) 0.008*x^2 - 1.8*x + 874
f <- f1(x1) + f2(x2) + f3(x3)
e <- rnorm(n, 0, 2)
y <- f + e

b <- gam(y ~ s(x1, k = 3)+s(x2, k = 3)+ s(x3, k = 3))
b3 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), sp = c(b$sp[1], b$sp[2]))
b2 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x3), sp = c(b$sp[1], b$sp[3]))
b1 <- gam(y ~ s(x2) + s(x3), sp = c(b$sp[2], b$sp[3]))

b0 <- gam(y~1)

(deviance(b1)-deviance(b))/deviance(b0)
(deviance(b2)-deviance(b))/deviance(b0)
(deviance(b3)-deviance(b))/deviance(b0)
```

But I don't understand results. For example, the model with only x1 and x2 has a deviance smaller than deviance with the three explanatory variable.

Does the method I used to extract variance explained by variable with three variables is correct?

Does it mean that there is a confounding effect in the global model? Or is there another explanation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did something wrong here:

```
b <- gam(y ~ s(x1, k = 3) + s(x2, k = 3) + s(x3, k = 3))
b3 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), sp = c(b$sp[1], b$sp[2]))
b2 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x3), sp = c(b$sp[1], b$sp[3]))
b1 <- gam(y ~ s(x2) + s(x3), sp = c(b$sp[2], b$sp[3]))
```

Why did you set `k = 3` in the first line, while not setting `k = 3` for the rest? Without specifying `k`, `s()` will take default value `k = 10`. Now you get a problem: `b1`, `b2`, `b3` are not nested in `b`.

In Simon Wood's original example, he left `k` unspecified, so that `k=10` is taken for all `s()`. In fact, you can vary `k` values, but you must gurantee that you always have the same `k` for the same covariate (to ensure nesting). For example, you can do:

```
b <- gam(y ~ s(x1, k = 4) + s(x2, k = 6) + s(x3, k = 3))
b3 <- gam(y ~ s(x1, k = 4) + s(x2, k = 6), sp = c(b$sp[1], b$sp[2]))  ## droping s(x3) from b
b2 <- gam(y ~ s(x1, k = 4) + s(x3, k = 3), sp = c(b$sp[1], b$sp[3]))  ## droping s(x2) from b
b1 <- gam(y ~ s(x2, k = 6) + s(x3, k = 3), sp = c(b$sp[2], b$sp[3]))  ## droping s(x1) from b
```

Then let's do:

```
(deviance(b1)-deviance(b))/deviance(b0)
# [1] 0.2073421
(deviance(b2)-deviance(b))/deviance(b0)
# [1] 0.4323154
(deviance(b3)-deviance(b))/deviance(b0)
# [1] 0.02094997
```

The positive values imply that dropping any model term will inflate the deviance, which is sensible as our true model have all three terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with you.
it still has something that I don't understand. Why I need to specify k (wich is the maximum degree of smoothing) if there is not smoothing optimization? For my point of view, specifying "sp = ..." implies that  there is no need for the optimization and so no need to set k.